# Failed to generate 1 second (BASCOM AVR)

Tags: microcontroller, bascom

I had a microcontroller trainer kit that includes ATMEGA8535 and 8MHZ xtal. I want to make simple program that switch off/on led every 1 sec. 
But it wont work, when I run the trainer, the delay seems to be 7 sec.

here the program with BASCOM AVR.

```
$regfile = "8535def.dat"
$crystal = 8000000

Config Porta = Output                                       

Config Timer1 = Timer , Prescale = 256    
Enable Timer1                             
On Timer1 Isr_von_timer1          
Enable Interrupts
Timer1 = 34285                          

Do
Loop
End

Isr_von_timer1:                          
Timer1 = 34285                                            
Toggle Porta.0                                              

Return
```

Comment: How did you determine the value of 34285 ? Maybe it needs to be around 5000 ?

Comment: I read this http://www.rn-wissen.de/index.php/Bascom_und_Timer (Germany). When I set to 5000, the delay seems to be 15 sec. :(

Comment: get the datasheet for the avr part,  have you read about the timers in that manual and how they work?  have you followed the clock through the clock tree to find where the divisors are and have you controlled and/or accounted for those divisors?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue: I forgot to activate the external xtal :).

Answer (score 0):

The correct value for timer1 using an 8 MHz oscillator with pre-scale=256 to turn on the output for one second and turn off for one second using the toggle command is 31249 (divisor - 1)